# Scala replacement for Arrays.binarySearch?

Tags: java, search, scala, programming-languages

Is there a replacement in Scala for Java's `int Arrays.binarySearch(Object[] array, object)`?

The problem is that Scala's Arrays are not covariant, so I would have to cast my `stringArray: Array[String]` like this first:

```
stringArray.asInstanceOf[Array[Object]]
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There isn't anything built in as far as I know, but you can use the [pimp-my-library pattern](https://coderwall.com/p/k_1jzw/scala-s-pimp-my-library-pattern-example) to accomplish this fairly easily.  Like so:

```
class ObjectArrayTools[T <: AnyRef](a: Array[T]) {                  
   def binarySearch(key: T) = {
     java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(a.asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]],key)
   }
}
implicit def anyrefarray_tools[T <: AnyRef](a: Array[T]) = new ObjectArrayTools(a)

scala> Array("a","fish","is","some","thing").binarySearch("some")
res26: Int = 3
scala> Array("a","fish","is","some","thing").binarySearch("bye")  
res28: Int = -2
```

You can add the other `java.util.Arrays` object methods into the same class if you need them too.

In general, I find it a good idea to get used to always importing a collection of your favorite Scala utilities.  It's so easy to add functionality like this that you may as well do it in general rather than keep typing `.asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]]`, and with a little effort you can make yourself significantly more productive.

Comment: What about `def indexOf (elem: A, from: Int) : Int` shouldn't this behave like binarySearch (although possibly slower?)

Comment: @soc Not with that signature, as `binarySearch` depends on keys being `Comparable`. IIRC, Java just casts and returns a run-time error, which isn't the kind of thing we want out of Scala. Furthermore, it only works on collections which are ordered, which, again, can't be statically enforced at the moment without an explosion in number of classes (there have been ideas).

Comment: If `binarySearch` depends on the items being `Comparable`, shouldn't we add a constraint such as `T <: Comparable[T]`?

Answer (score 53):

Scala 2.11 added [`scala.collection.Searching`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.0-M3/src/library/scala/collection/Searching.scala) to the standard library.  It uses binary search for indexed sequences and linear search otherwise.

```
import scala.collection.Searching._
Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).search(3)
```

Comment: How can i tell the search method that my array is sorted and it can use binary search?

Comment: @samy Your collection must be sorted to use `search`.  That is, if you invoke `search` on a sequence that is not sorted, the results are undefined.

Comment: thanks for the explanation but the it seems the method uses linear search on my array of type Array[String] it is magnitudes slower than java.util.Arrays.binarySearch()

Comment: I've not tested the implementation, but I'd be very surprised if it doesn't work as advertised.  You might want to post a new question with details of what you've tested and results you've seen.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in scala 2.11 which was the version i was using, https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9605

Comment: Note that the behavior is different from Java `Collections.binarySearch` (or `Arrays.binarySearch`) when the element is _not_ present in the collection. Java returns `-1 -insertionPoint`, while Scala returns an index > 0. Thus, searching for `3` in `[1, 2, 4, 5]` would return `-3` in Java and `2` in Scala. I personally prefer the Java return value because I can differentiate between the element being present vs absent in the list.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar You can easily differentiate these cases with the Scala Searching API because the `SearchResult` returned is either a `Found` or an `InsertionPoint`.  Use a `match` to tell which case it is, and the two cases will be explicit for anyone reading the code.

Comment: @JoePallas You're right, although explicitly returning an `Either` type would have been better IMO. Also, it's not documented which one is returned if there's a match among duplicates. After looking at the source code, it seems to be arbitrary.

Comment: You are a savior!

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are funny beasts. If you try the code in the example provided with 'ObjectArrayTools' with this:

```
Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).binarySearch(3)
```

You get

```
error: value binarySearch is not a member of Array[Int]
          Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).binarySearch(3)
```

For what's going on with Arrays in Scala refer to [this document](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_38.html). In any case, you could use this code instead, although it uses Seq instead of Array. However, it has the added bonus of using an Ordering (which just so happens to also be a Java Comparator. So you can customize the ordered behavior if needed.)

```
import _root_.scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import java.util.{Collections, List => JList}
class SearchableSeq[T](a: Seq[T])(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]) {
    val list: JList[T] = a.toList
    def binarySearch(key: T): Int = Collections.binarySearch(list, key, ordering)
}
implicit def seqToSearchable[T](a: Seq[T])(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]) = 
        new SearchableSeq(a)(ordering)
```

Some examples:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).binarySearch(3)
res0: Int = 2

scala> List(1D, 2D, 3D, 4D, 5D).binarySearch(3.5)
res1: Int = -4

scala> List("a","fish","is","some","thing").binarySearch("bye")
res2: Int = -2
```

Comment: accessing java List by index can be very inefficient

Comment: @piotr. That depends on what's backing a list. For example, an ArrayList is backed by an Array; they both provide similar performance in terms of getting an element by index.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is suboptimal. `Collections.binarySearch` checks if provided list implements RandomAccess interface ("If the specified list does not implement the RandomAccess interface and is large, this method will do an iterator-based binary search that performs O(n) link traversals and O(log n) element comparisons."). None of lists provided by JavaConverters implements that interface.
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T))

Comment: Good catch. I hadn't realized that. It looks like scala added `scala.collection.Searching` in 2.11. So instead you could use:

`import scala.collection.Searching._; Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).search(3)`

Answer (score 1):

It not that hard to just write it in scala

```
  object BSearch {
    def interative[T](array: Array[T], value: T)(implicit arithmetic: Numeric[T]): Int = {
      var left: Int = 0;
      var right: Int = array.length - 1;
      while (right > left) {
        val mid = left + (right - left) / 2
        val comp = arithmetic.compare(array(mid), value)
        if (comp == 0)
          return mid; //negative if test < value
        else if (comp > 0) //list(mid) > value
          right = mid - 1;
        else if (comp < 0) //list(mid) < value
          left = mid + 1;
      }
      -1;
    }


BSearch.interative(array, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Been some years since this question was raised, thought to make some comparison test, hopefully it can help some to decide:

```
import scala.collection.Searching._
import _root_.scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import java.util.{Collections, List => JList}
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class ObjectArrayTools[T <: Int](a: Array[T]) {
   def binarySearch(key: T) = {
     java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(a.asInstanceOf[Array[Int]],key)
   }
}

class SearchableSeq[T](a: Seq[T])(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]) {
    val list: JList[T] = a.toList
    def binarySearch2(key: T): Int = Collections.binarySearch(list, key, ordering)
}

object BinarySearch {
  implicit def anyrefarray_tools[T <: Int](a: Array[T]) = new ObjectArrayTools(a)
  implicit def seqToSearchable[T](a: Seq[T])(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]) =
          new SearchableSeq(a)(ordering)

  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    val informationArray = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,18,20,22,23,25,26)
    val informationList = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,18,20,22,23,25,26)
    //val sortedArray = sortList(informationArray)
    val sortedArray = informationArray
    val sortedList = informationList

    for(x <- 0 to 2) {
      val startTime = System.nanoTime
      val result = binarySearch(sortedArray, 5)
      val result2 = binarySearch(sortedArray, 19)
      println(s"Custom search time elapsed: ${(System.nanoTime - startTime)}")

      val startTime2 = System.nanoTime
      val result3 = sortedArray.search(5)
      val result4 = sortedArray.search(19)
      println(s"Scala search time elapsed: ${(System.nanoTime - startTime2)}")

      val startTime3 = System.nanoTime
      val result5 = sortedArray.binarySearch(5)
      val result6 = sortedArray.binarySearch(19)
      println(s"Java search casting time elapsed: ${(System.nanoTime - startTime3)}")

      val startTime4 = System.nanoTime
      val result7 = sortedList.binarySearch2(5)
      val result8 = sortedList.binarySearch2(19)
      println(s"Java search as list time elapsed: ${(System.nanoTime - startTime4)}")


      val startTime9 = System.nanoTime
      val result10 = binarySearchWithImplicitConversion(sortedArray, 5)
      val result11 = binarySearchWithImplicitConversion(sortedArray, 19)
      println(s"Custom generic time elapsed: ${(System.nanoTime - startTime9)}")

      println("---")
    }
  }

  /*def sortList(list:Array[Int]):Array[Int] = {
    import com.walcron.etc.Quicksort._
    quickSort(list)
  }*/

  //def binarySearch[T <% Ordered[T]](list:Array[T], valueToBeSearch:T)(implicit t:ClassTag[T]):Int =  {
  def binarySearch(list:Array[Int], valueToBeSearch:Int):Int =  {
    def search(start:Int, end:Int):Int = {
      val pos = ((end - start) / 2) + start
      val curr = list(pos)

      if(curr == valueToBeSearch) {
        pos
      }
      else if((end - start) <= 1) {
        -1 * (pos + 1) // Indicates the value should be inserted
      }
      else if(valueToBeSearch > curr) {
        search(pos, end)
      }
      else {
        search(start, pos)
      }
    }

    search(0, list.length)
  }

  def binarySearchWithImplicitConversion[T <% Ordered[T]](list:Array[T], valueToBeSearch:T)(implicit t:ClassTag[T]):Int =  {
    def search(start:Int, end:Int):Int = {
      val pos = ((end - start) / 2) + start
      val curr = list(pos)

      if(curr == valueToBeSearch) {
        pos
      }
      else if((end - start) <= 1) {
        -1 * (pos + 1) // Indicates the value should be inserted
      }
      else if(valueToBeSearch > curr) {
        search(pos, end)
      }
      else {
        search(start, pos)
      }
    }

    search(0, list.length)
  }
}
```

The returned result after 3 runs (as Scala compiler really do need some boost)

```
Custom search time elapsed: 873373
Scala search time elapsed: 9322723
Java search casting time elapsed: 126380
Java search as list time elapsed: 7375826
Custom generic time elapsed: 4421972
---
Custom search time elapsed: 10372
Scala search time elapsed: 34885
Java search casting time elapsed: 10861
Java search as list time elapsed: 104596
Custom generic time elapsed: 57964
---
Custom search time elapsed: 9121
Scala search time elapsed: 31667
Java search casting time elapsed: 11815
Java search as list time elapsed: 53387
Custom generic time elapsed: 60773
```

In general, java binary search performed way better; while scala's search did pretty bad. There was also another noticeable performance, it seems that generic typing implicitly drags the performance here badly(so maybe someone can help fix the generic type)...but indirectly it shows a big performance impact.

Answer (score -1):

@moshe-beeri

If you were going to write it in Scala, why would you write it in Java in Scala? Why not actually write it in Scala?

```
def split(list:List[Char]): (List[Char], List[Char]) = {
    val len = list.size
    (list.slice(0, len/2), list.slice(len/2,len))
}

def search(target: Char, list: List[Char]):Boolean = {
    list match {
        case Nil => false
        case head :: Nil =>  if (head == target) true else false
        case _ => {
            val c = split(list)
            if (c._1.last >= target) search(target, c._1) else search(target, c._2)
        }
    }
}
```