# Scala's toList function appears to be slow

Tags: scala

I was under the impression that calling seq.toList() on an immutable Seq would be making a new list which is sharing the structural state from the first list. We're finding that this could be really slow and I'm not sure why. It *is* just sharing the structural state, correct? I can't see why it'd be making an n-time copy of all the elements when it knows they'll never change.

Comment: can you specify what the criteria is for it to be classed as being fast?

Comment: So i think criteria was that it appeared to much much slower than just newing up a simple object. The coworker of mine who was doing the simple test was actually comparing it against the JWrappers (using the implicit conversions to turn the seq into a list. I mean- when we ran over 1M items, the different was that the toList function was twice as slow (15 seconds for JWrappers and implicit conversions vs 30 seconds for toList. I have to be missing something here.

Comment: Show your code? We can only guess what your benchmark is here.

Comment: We are using the 3rd strategy from [1] so that we can use Collections.binarySearch() in Scala 2.10. Notice the import java.util.List => JList here and how it does an implicit conversion from a.toList to JList[T] using the asScalaList implicit. If we do this without the toList, it's fast, adding in the toList, it's slow. Any ideas?

[1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226947/scala-replacement-for-arrays-binarysearch

Comment: I'm debugging through the toList function right now and it looks like it's creating a list buffer and calling ++= which is calling "initialSeq take size", thus it looks like it's actually iterating through the seq to grab all the items to add to the ListBuffer and then calling ListBUffer.result. Am I missing somethign here? I really just want to know if the toList is iterating through all the items in the initial seq.

Comment: Here's some code:

     (0 to 1000000).foreach(List(Seq((0 to 512)))) takes about 138ms 

while

     (0 to 1000000).foreach((0 to 512).toList) takes about 5.5 seconds.

Comment: Nm, I'm a dummy- List(List()) is a List[List]]. But still- I'm trying to find a way to turn a seq into a list and not have it be O(n)

Comment: Calling seq.iterator.toList appears to be shared structural state- thus it's fast as crap. Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: @CoreyJ.Nolet  `seq.iterator.toList` is slower - your benchmark code should be: `(0 to 1000000).foreach(_ => (0 to 512).toList)` (you forgot `_ =>`)

Comment: Yeah I was typing it by hand- i had that in the real version. I think I accidentally put a Seq(0 to 512) in there instead of just (0 to 512).toList which, for obvious reasons, was causing it to be faster (1 element seq vs 512 element seq).

So my next question is- I assumed the toList was just wrapping the seq and I guess I was rather surprised to find out that it's actually creating a new List each time. Why is this so? Is there another alternative? It's actually faster to use the java conversion wrappers than it is to do a toList().

Answer (score 7):

A `List` in Scala is a particular data structure: instances of `::` each containing a value, followed by `Nil` at the end of the chain.

If you `toList` a `List`, it will take `O(1)` time.  If you `toList` on *anything else* then it must be converted into a `List`, which involves `O(n)` object allocations (all the `::` instances).

So you have to ask whether you *really* want a `scala.collection.immutable.List`.  That's what `toList` gives you.

Comment: I understand this point exactly but iterator.toList appears to be constant time. Maybe I'll do some more research under the hood to figure out why this is so

Comment: @CoreyJ.Nolet - You're just mismeasuring.  You get nearly perfect `O(n)` with something like `(1 to n).iterator.toList`.

Comment: If I'm mismeasuring then why is seq.toList several orders of magnitude slower. Also, how are you determining this? to iterator.toList is on the order of 100's of ms and seq.toList is on the order of 10's of seconds. What else am missing? If both are o(n) then I could imagine object creation time wouldn't the hinderance here.

Comment: @CoreyJ.Nolet - Because you're mismeasuring.  `(1 to n).toList` is faster.  I'm running microbenchmarks.  What are you doing that's taking tens of seconds?  You should run out of memory long before then.

Comment: Look at my example above. (0 to n).toList isn't what I was doing. Do 1000000 iterations of (0 to 512).toList and compare it against 1000000 iterations of (0 to 512).iterator.toList() and tell me which appears to be slower... also tell me how I'm mismeasuring please. From what I'm gathering, (and I haven't fully stepped through this in the debugger yet) is that the iterator.toList appears to be wrapping vs the the other Range.toList which appears to be creating a new ListBuffer (causing it to be O(n). The latter part I did step through in the debugger and verify.

Comment: @CoreyJ.Nolet - Does your final answer depend on what you're doing inside the iteration?  If not, the JVM may detect that and throw away the pointless work.

Comment: I;m also on Scala 2.10 if it helps

Comment: Good question- I'm more just trying to make sense of what myself and coworkers are seeing and trying to explain the tests we've been running. I'm not @ my work box right now and I just realized i have Scala 2.11 installed on my laptop so I'm going to downgrade that to Scala 2.10 and see if I can reproduce it @ home. It does appear running my example w/ Scala 2.11 is much much faster (on the order of 500ms to a 1sec vs 5+ seconds in Scala 2.10)

Comment: Ok. I think I may have been doing something a tad wrong in one of my tests. I think I was doing Seq(0 to 512).iterator.toList which was creating a 1 element Seq with a Range(0 to 512).

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly why- it seems like it'd be faster to wrap the Scala Seq as a Java List and then wrap it again as a Scala list then it would be to call toList. So strange... It's going to be n-time anyways to do size() and foreach(), etc... so why not save the cost of creation?

Comment: @CoreyJ.Nolet - Because `List` is a particular data type.  If you ask for a `List` you get one.  It's **not** the abstract some-sort-of-sequential-collection that a Java list is.  It's a very particular eagerly-evaluated immutable singly-linked list.  If you don't want to create one when you haven't got one, _don't ask for one_!

Comment: The reason I care is that sometimes APIs ask for one and I have no choice. The singly-linked list part still doesn't explain why I can't just provide a class which extends list and provides methods that proxy the underlying data. The fact that it's a singly-linked list, I could imagine, makes that one even easier, because I know my size() is going to be an n-time operation anyways, right? Since all other collections already provide foreach, forall, collection, etc.... why does that mean wrapping the list to provide constant-time creation is bad?

Comment: @CoreyJ.Nolet - You can't extend `List`; it's sealed.  It's sealed so that you can safely pattern match on it.  Pattern matching is one of _the_ reasons to use a `List`.  Also, you are assuming that the APIs don't have a good reason to ask for a List (i.e. _that exact_ data structure).  Maybe they don't, maybe they do, but they've decided that they do and so you have either to comply or find a different API.

Comment: Also- I haven't checked yet, but if list is the problem... what are my guarantees with respect to doing List.toSeq() and arrays.toSeq? Are those going to be constant-time in Scala?

Comment: @CoreyJ.Nolet - Those are constant time.  `List` already is a `Seq` so `toSeq` is basically a no-op.  `Array` has a `Seq` wrapper class `WrappedArray`.

Comment: Ah, good point about it being sealed. Makes sense now why there's no wrapper around it.  I also didn't realize classes has to be sealed to pattern match, I just thought they needed to provide unapply(). (I'm still learning the ins and outs of Scala if you can't tell).

Comment: @CoreyJ.Nolet - Unapply is enough, but if it's sealed the compiler can check that you've covered all the possible cases.  That's really helpful for correctness.

Comment: Rex, you've been a huge help! ANd you've also helped me understand why Spark's custom json conversions (because DefaultScalaModule for Jackson is so slow) uses Map and Seq for Json Object & Array rather than Map and List. We mistakingly copied their code and did a toList on the parsed Seq's so that we didn't have to change all of our code that's already dependent on Lists but now I think we're going to scrape through and make this change now that you've opened my eyes.

Comment: Is it safe to say that Seq -> Scala what Collection -> Java?

Answer (score 1):

Sharing structural state is possible for particular operations on particular data structures.

With the List data structure in Scala, my understanding is that every element refers to the next, starting from the head through the tail, so a singly linked list.

From a structural state sharing perspective, consider the restrictions placed on this from the internal data structure perspective. Adding an element to the head of a List (X) effectively creates a new list (X') with the new element as the head of X' and the old list (X) as the tail. For this particular operation, internal state can be shared completely.

The same operation above can be applied to create a new List (X'), with the new element as the head of X' and any element from X as the tail, as long as you accept that the tail will be the element you choose from X, plus all additional elements it already has in it's data structure.

When you think about it logically, each data structure has an internal structure that allows some operations to be performed with simple shared internal structure and other operations requiring more invasive and costly computations.

The key from my perspective here is having an understanding of the constraints placed on the operations by the internal data structure itself.

For example, consider the same operations above on a doubly linked list data structure and you will see that there are quite different restrictions.

Personally, I find drawing out an understanding of the internal structure can be helpful in understanding the consequences of particular operations.

In the case of the toList operation on an arbitrary sequence, with no knowledge of the arbitrary sequences internal data structure, one has to therefore assume O(n). List.toList has the obvious performance advantage of already being a list.

Comment: See I understand all that from the Orderskys "programming in scala" book but why would an iterator be able to be turned into a list in constant time and not a seq. I think my first assumption about Seq.toList is that there would have been a wrapper to do the xonversion so that O(n) could have been the worst case only when size or foreach operations are called. I don't see any documentation of these semantics either which is making it trial and error to figure it out.