# Can't call overloaded Java method from Scala generic method

Tags: scala

I am trying to wrap `java.util.Array.binarySearch` in a generic fashion in Scala, but the following code doesn't work:

```
 def binarySlice[T](minValue: T, array: Array[T]): Array[T] = {
   val i = java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(array, minValue)
   val idx = if (i > 0) i else -i - 1
   array.slice(idx, array.length)
 }
```

The error is: `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'binarySearch'`. What should I do to make this code work?

Comment: Which binarySearch method are you trying to use? There are two implementations with `Array[T]` but they need another parameters.

Comment: The one with only 2 arguments, the second one being the target value?

Comment: There are two binarySearch methods with Array[T] argument, none of them have 2 arguments. `public static <T> int binarySearch(T[] a, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)` and `public static <T> int binarySearch(T[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)`

Answer (score 1):

See: [Scala replacement for Arrays.binarySearch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4228023/651140):

```
def binarySlice[T <: AnyRef](minValue: T, array: Array[T]): Array[T] = {
   val i = java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(array.asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]], minValue)
   val idx = if (i > 0) i else -i - 1
   array.slice(idx, array.length)
 }
```

You can not use it for primitives. It is work-around for int:

```
scala> binarySlice[java.lang.Integer](3, Array(0,3,7,8))
res6: Array[Integer] = Array(3, 7, 8)
```